# Django 3.1.4 - AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.AppUser' that has not been installed even though app is in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

I've encountered a very odd issue, that I'm suspecting I'll have to put in an issue for with the django team. I've followed the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) to great success at setting the following custom user model:

`apps.users.models.py`

```py
...

# Here, the genders choices are declared in models.py
class Genders(models.TextChoices):
    UNSPECIFIED = '', _('Unspecified')
    MALE = 'M', _('Male')
    FEMALE = 'F', _('Female')


# Create your models here.
class AppUser(AbstractUser):
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=6, choices=Genders.choices, default=Genders.UNSPECIFIED, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    weight = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def age(self):
        return relativedelta(date.today(), self.birthday).years if self.birthday else None

    def get_eligable_age_divisions(self) -> 'QuerySet[WeightClass]':
        query = self.__get_bound_query(self.age)

        # TODO Genders being in the user models module is causing a circular reference.
        # move genders to separate module caused the appUser module to appear as not registered
        # pylint: disable=import-outside-toplevel
        from apps.divisions.models import AgeDivision

        return AgeDivision.objects.filter(query)
...
```

`apps.divisions.models`

```py
...
class WeightClass(models.Model):
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, blank=True, choices=Genders.choices, default=Genders.UNSPECIFIED)
    lower_bound = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    upper_bound = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
...
```

`settings.py`

```py
...


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'apps.users',
    'apps.divisions',
    ...
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.AppUser'

...
```

The above works with no issues. However, I really don't like my imports anywhere but at the top level, as it adds unnecessary confusion about module dependencies. My solution to this was to move the `Genders` definition to it's own module:

`apps.users.choices.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Genders(models.TextChoices):
    UNSPECIFIED = '', _('Unspecified')
    MALE = 'M', _('Male')
    FEMALE = 'F', _('Female')
```

Then, change the imports in the `apps.users.models.py` and `apps.divisions.models.py` files to prevent a circular reference. However, this being the ONLY change, I'm suddenly getting an issues where I can't even run `python manage.py showmigrations` without getting `AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.AppUser' that has not been installed`.

My project is hosted on GitHub, so I've create a branch demonstrating the issue. Here's the diff you so can see all that I changed: https://github.com/thomasrea0113/leaderboard/compare/without-user-model-issue...user-model-issue.

Comment: Likely you refer to it in an app that is in `INSTALLED_APPS` *before* the `users` app.

Comment: I don't think that's it. It works fine when `Genders` is declared in the `apps.users.models.py` module directly. The issue only appears when I move that declaration to it's own module. If it were an app ordering issue, then the issue would present itself in both scenarios.